# Firebase and notification issues

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

My problem with the database in Firebase, I developed a chat app and it worked, now I tried to add the notification feature.

My code says when the user press the send button, inside the on click check the status of the other user (there is a table of the users status in database), if it is offline, add in database a notification table with receiver id a notification.

On create method I checked if there is inside of the notification table an id with same current user id, show the notification.

The problem is the first run the app is great and it shows the notification after I press send and the other user is offline without obstacles, but after that i remove the notification from database to test again, even if I press the back button to get back to previous activity the notification is added to the database, even if I moved to another app, it will add the notification to the database. I could not find what the problem is.

inside on create method the checking:

```
    onlineOfflineUserStatus = "online";

    databaseStatus = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://chatim-2ed18.firebaseio.com/status");

    databaseStatus.child(subString).setValue(onlineOfflineUserStatus);


    databaseNotification = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://chatim-2ed18.firebaseio.com/Notification");

    databaseNotification.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if ( dataSnapshot.child(subString).exists()){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext() , messageActivity.class);

                    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext() , 1 , intent , 0 );

                    Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                            .setContentTitle("New Message")
                            .setContentText("please press here")
                            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                            .addAction(android.R.drawable.sym_action_chat, "Chat", pendingIntent)
                            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_def_app_icon)
                            .build();

                    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

            }else {

                Log.i("the notification", " is not  here ");
                System.out.println("the notification is not here ...ooooo");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

inside on click the fab button:

```
            databaseStatus.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                    if (dataSnapshot.child(subStringGetName).getValue().equals("offline")) {

                        addNotification();

                    } else {
                        Log.i("the status ", " is.. online");
                        System.out.println("the status is ... online");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



        }
    });
```

add notification method:

public void addNotification(){

```
    databaseNotification.child(subStringGetName).child("From").setValue(subString);
    databaseNotification.child(subStringGetName).child("To").setValue(subStringGetName);
    databaseNotification.child(subStringGetName).child("Body").setValue("Hellooo");


}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots if you can paste code.

Comment: @StephanVierkant sorry i will try to edit my post and add the codes

Comment: Just a comment, but...maybe do not store emails inside of your database. Use user-keys (firebase auth) instead. And to answer your question: Think about cloud functions that trigger on database inserts (new message) and sending gcm messages to the other participants.

Comment: @JacksOnF1re thank u for ur comment, i am considering not to store emails inside the database, it is just a prototype. and i will think about cloud functions. i have heard about it two days ago and i wanna test it.